# Turned keyed array into single dimensional array with values only

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I'm doing a PDO Query, using the `(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)` this returns the following result.

```
0 => string 'Sarah' (length=3)
1 => string 'Lisa' (length=3)
2 => string 'Katherine' (length=3)
3 => string 'Laura' (length=3)
4 => string 'Hannah' (length=3)
5 => string 'Becky' (length=3)
6 => string 'Stacey' (length=3)
7 => string 'Lauren' (length=3)
```

is there a php function to convert the array to values only, I'm looking for data similar to.

```
['Sarah', 'Lisa', 'Katherine', 'Laura', 'Hannah.....
```

Comment: That's *exactly* what you already have.

Comment: how rude, they are keyed by 0 to 7, I want to turn the array into a single dimensional one.

Comment: All arrays have numerical keys unless they are associative arrays. *It's how they work*. Also, there was nothing rude about that statement. It was factual and nothing offensive should be construed from it.

Comment: If you have an array you must have keys.  What you have is a _single dimensional_ one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map. A map is a type that associates values to keys. This type is optimized for several different uses; it can be treated as an array, list (vector), hash table (an implementation of a map), dictionary, collection, stack, queue, and probably more. As array values can be other arrays, trees and multidimensional arrays are also possible.
>
> ```
> <?php
> $array = array("foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
> var_dump($array);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> ```
> array(4) {
>   [0]=>
>   string(3) "foo"
>   [1]=>
>   string(3) "bar"
>   [2]=>
>   string(5) "hello"
>   [3]=>
>   string(5) "world"
> }
> ```

This actually means, that your example, i.e. `['Sarah', 'Lisa', 'Katherine', 'Laura', 'Hannah']`, is actually this:

```
0 => Sarah
1 => Lisa
2 => Katherine
3 => Laura
4 => Hannah
```

How you display it on the page depends on you from that moment.